# WebAPI 2 secure routing parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I have a situation where I don't want to pass logged-in userid in API route parameter. 
For example there is a WebAPI [GET or POST] endpoint 'api/getUserDetails/{id}'. This id is passed to another layer to get the user data.

```
public RestResult getUserDetails(int uID)
{
  int uID = getFromHeaderCookie();
  var userDetails = someService.GetUserDetail(uID);
  return userDetails;
}
```

Here id is passed as route parameter and by changing the Id value anyone can see the other users data.

So now I want that the url should be like 'api/getUserDetails' and I am reading Id from header Cookie saved at the time of login. using ActionFilters I can manage to get the Id.

```
public RestResult getUserDetails( )
    {
      int uID = getFromHeaderCookie();
      var userDetails = someService.GetUserDetail(uID);
      return userDetails;
    }
```

This is working but not looking good as there are other methods where I want to secure UserId.
Is there any way to remove `int uID = getFromHeaderCookie();` and use some custom model binder to inject userID in controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try Oauth, and get user info from [ClaimsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx), just need to add Authorization(such as Bearer AccessToken) when request url.